# Why does my window smell like BO?

Tags: windows, smell

I have a west facing window that seems to be emanating a horrible body odor smell. I've isolated it to the window, since I can close the cellular shades and it limits the smell. Additionally, if I stick my nose into a crack between the shade and the window frame, the smell is particularly strong.

It's also stronger in the late afternoon when the sun is beating directly on the window.

I've tried cleaning the area thoroughly, but that didn't help.

What could be causing this? How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe you have a small critter that got stuck somewhere around the window and died. Or perhaps a cat sprayed the area, (inside or outside) that does clean so easily.

Comment: A leak that has allowed mold to grow inside the wall?

Comment: Trouble is that smell is highly subjective.  See what odor friends identify, as that may help narrow down the source. Is this a new window? Can it be opened?  and so on.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback everyone. I'll continue to investigate, and if I find the answer, I'll post back here.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem. I discovered the body odor smell was coming from the fly screen. I live by the beach. After a weather event involving both wind and rain I noticed there salt deposits left. When the sun beats down on the salt deposits the BO smell is most prevelant. I have to remove the flyscreen and give it a thorough clean with sugar soap and a brush to get rid of the smell.

Comment: You can spray hydrogen peroxide on the area, that will kill mold and many other items.

Answer (score 0):

**Check for Asian Lady Beetles**

In my neck of the woods, this is an invasive (And smelly) species. For some reason, they seem to love gathering in windowsills. Science people say they are looking for warmth in the cool season.

[Science People Talking About Asian Lady Beetles](https://www.canr.msu.edu/news/why_are_there_lady_bugs_on_my_windowsill#:%7E:text=On%20days%20where%20the%20wind,spring%20when%20days%20grow%20longer.)

The smell is described as ". . . a mixture of nutlike, green bell pepper, potato, and moldy odors."

Even if they're not there now, the secretions can remain for some time.

[image]